# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when initializing a matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error when executing the program that instantiate a class `Matrice` and creating it in its constructor.

here is my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

class Matrice{
public:
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat;

  Matrice(){
    for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
      for(int j=0; j < 2; ++j) {
        mat[i][j] = rand()%(10-0)+0;
      }
    }
  }
};


int main(){
  Matrice mat1;
  return 0;
}
```

can someone enlighten me.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] next time, without it, it is off-topic. Anyhow, you have created vectors but they don't have any space allocated to them.

Comment: You never gave any size to your vector(s). Therefore, `mat[i][j] = ...` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the code looks pretty MVCE to me. Didn't compile it, but it's got constructor, use, illegal access, and predictible core-dump.

Comment: It's C and V, but not M. Just creating an object to invoke some code that runs in a constructor can be reduced even further. So can the `rand()` call. Or even the nested vectors could be reduced to just one. Doing this strictly helps finding errors yourself. In this case, `#include <vector> int main() {std::vector<int> v; v[0] = 1;}` would have been enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Matrice(){
    for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
        mat.push_back(std::vector<int>());
        for(int j=0; j < 2; ++j) {
            mat[i].push_back(rand()%(10-0)+0);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Explanation: vectors require the `push_back` function call to add an element to the end of the vector and will automatically reallocate space for the vector if it goes over the size originally allocated for the vector.  Since it is a vector of vectors, you first need to push back an arbitrary vector, then at each arbitrary vector stored in mat[i], we `push_back` the random integer value needed.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, updated my post.  Fairly new to stackoverflow so I appreciate the information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to resize your matrix before accessing elements:

```
mat.resize(3);
for( int i=0; i < 3; ++i)
{
  mat[i].resize(2);
}
```

Comment: Using the member initializer list, `Matrice(): mat(3, std::vector<int>(2))`, would be a bit cleaner. Compiler cam probably pull some sneaky optimizations as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `std::vector` incorrectly.  Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

The `[]` operator returns a reference to an existing value.  Unlike `std::map`, it does not insert a new value.  Use `std::vector::push_back()` to add elements to a vector.